# How to make a field editable while creating, but read only in existing objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've a django Model, and want to be able to set an id while creating. But once created, the id of existing object shouldn't be editable.

```
class Vehicle:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

I see that I need to turn do "editable=True" (which is the default) on the id field, but this would allow editing the id field later on as well.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield?

Comment: If you say `editable=False` you will get the behavior you want as the default. Django creates a UUID on create and it is not modified by the user later on. Or did I misunderstand? Do you want to edit the ID manually when you create the object? If so, you should not do that.

Comment: That is right. I'm basically having a client (mobile app) which can send the id (UUID) to the backend, and hence Vehicle.id is being set by the client. 
Without that id, we've to wait for the backend response, which would contain the UUID set by django.